# What is the operating voltage of Media access controllers?

Tags: phy, mac

Do MAC and PHY operate on same voltage levels?

Comment: What is your question? Both have a common interface and Most chips today will operate at 3V3. so at least the common interface needs to have compatible voltages. Internally they may use different voltages like lower ones for digital cores

Comment: Their datasheets will answer that question. You know which ones you are using; we don't, so we can only guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voltage is only related to the Physical Layer. MAC is at the Link Layer where the Physical Layer is abstracted. However, depending on the implementation, some MAC are constrained to the physical layer to benefit from its characteristics but still the voltage is a physical property. You have to specify which MAC you are interested in. Note also that the physical layer can be optical or wireless or any other medium.